# Xbap application in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-application, xaml-browser-application

We want to make a big project on top of SharePoint 2010.

Our thinking is to make the project a WPF web application (xbap) due to the amount of roubustness and features that xbap offers.

I would like to know what are the disadvantages/constraints that we might encounter:

- Can we make a full wpf xbap application run on top of SP2010 without any issues (and what are the issues)
- Are there any limitations, security limitations, can we acces xbap from the Internet.
- Any other limitations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use client side code like the Client Side API or Web Services for connecting to SharePoint just like silverlight.

XBAP is only for IE/Firefox
XBAP requires the correct version of .net preinstalled
XBAP must be installed onto client computer
Can run full trust

**XBAP is installed on first access and re-installed/updated if the XBAP changes similiar to ClickOnce deployments.

Silverlight is cross platform and supports more browsers
Requires small browser plug in and will re-direct user to install required components.
Restricted Permissions

**Silverlight Client installation is a lightweight version of the .net framework, so as long as the client is installed the version of .net doesn't matter.

If you are working in a controlled environment and know the .net version installed on clients than XBAP gives you more options.

If your base is diverse OS (Windows, OSX, Linux) or Browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari) or you can't guarantee they have the correct .Net version installed I would go with Silverlight.

There are a number of dicussions posted on StackOverflow as well (just a couple)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771093/silverlight-4-and-xbap

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758070/what-does-wpf-still-have-to-offer-over-silverlight-4

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please elaborate on the following:
x-Must install on client? do you mean that everytime the user opens the xbap application, he has to download it to use it?
x-Does the .net framework have to be installed on the client machine?(isn't it the same for silverlight?)
Thanks again for your help